# how to give loginredirect in cakedc, Cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakedc

How to give loginredirect in cakephp while using cakedc Users plugin and also tell where these changes are to be done src/controller/AppController or  vendor/cakedc/users/src/Controller/AppController

```
AppContoller of cakedc users plugin
    class AppController extends BaseController
    {
        public function initialize()
        {
            parent::initialize();
            $this->loadComponent('Security');
            $this->loadComponent('Csrf');
            $this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth', ['loginAction' => ['controller' => 'Blogs','action' => 'index']]);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update defaults in Auth component configuration after the plugin is loaded, like this:

```
$this->Auth->config('loginAction', [...your url...]);
```

Or you can use the config based plugin initialization as suggested here https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Configuration.md

Comment: Thank you but it redirect me with prefix /users. So how i am going to connect src code.

Comment: set the prefix to false in the url array